# initializationError in Eclipse when @PrepareForTest is at method but at class

Tags: eclipse, junit4, powermock

Small example, using jUnit 4.11, Mockito 2.6.3, PowerMock 1.7.0RC4:

```
public class TheClass {

    public static int giveMeNumber() {
        return 70;
    }

    public static int giveMeThatNumber(int it) {
        return it;
    }
}
```

and

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.*;
import org.mockito.*;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.*;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.*;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
// @PrepareForTest(TheClass.class)
public class TheTestClass {

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(TheClass.class)
    public void test1() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(TheClass.class);
        Mockito.when(TheClass.giveMeNumber()).thenReturn(13);
        System.out.println(TheClass.giveMeNumber());
    }

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(TheClass.class)
    public void test2() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(TheClass.class);
        Mockito.when(TheClass.giveMeThatNumber(25)).thenReturn(50);
        System.out.println(TheClass.giveMeThatNumber(25));
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        System.out.println("Hey, I do not want a @Prepare...d class!");
    }
}
```

The dependencies are loaded with Maven, the `pom.xml` is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>stackoverflow.bowi</groupId>
    <artifactId>place.of.prepareForTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Place of PrepareForTest</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <powermock.version>1.7.0RC4</powermock.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run those tests in eclipse (right click at class name, *Run as...*, *JUnit test*), they pass (not actually checking anything, I know :-) ). When I run them **alone** (right click at method name, *Run as...*, *JUnit test*), they fail with an `initializationError [Runner: JUnit 4] (0,000s)` without any trace.

Strangely, when I remove the `@PrepareForTest(TheClass.class)` from the method signatures and uncomment it in the class signature, all three run fine both together and alone.

But now look: `test3()` says it does not want a "prepared" `TheClass`. What I thought was correct, is to move the `@PrepareForTest(TheClass.class)` from the class signature to the signatures of the methods that need it (`test1()` and `test2()`), like it was before but failed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to the documentation, this should work ( https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.5/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html ) ... just to be sure: please put up a [mcve] that gives the fail as well. Maybe you accidentally touched something else too when reworking your code.

Comment: What is missing? The `import` statements or the `pom.xml`?

Comment: The exact java code that gives the error.

Comment: I've only removed the `import` statements from `TheTestClass`, the rest of the code is exactly my demo code that produces the error. I've also reviewed the whole question and code for clarity, I hope it is better now.

Comment: You are explaining that you *only* moved the prepare statement to the test methods. But you also say that you removed the import?! I dont have powermockito installed (and dont wish to install that), so please: read [mcve] and make sure to include the *exact* code that gives you the problem. Instead of claiming: "here is working code which I slightly changed and now it fails"

Comment: Okay, I think I understand you now. I've now flipped the question to "here is working but forbidden code, when changing it to legal it fails" to "here is legal but failing code, when I would make an illegal change, it would work" and added the `pom.xml` and `import` statements.

Comment: @GhostCat, does it now meet the requirements?